# If $P(a_n\leq X_n\leq b_n)\to1$ and $a_n\to0,b_n\to0$ then $X_n\to\delta_0$ in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> If $P(a_n\leq X_n\leq b_n)\to1$ and $a_n\to0,b_n\to0$ then prove that $X_n\to\delta_0$ in distribution.

Here $\delta_0$ is the degenerate random variable putting all its mass at the point $0$.

I do not really see how one can start on this. Deaing with 3 sequences at once is kind of complicated.

Any hint/help will be appreciated.

Comment: The thing is, you don't really have 3 sequences, but only one sequence of $X_n$. It's distribution is only known as an asymptotic, but still, you just need to start as a proof of convergence of random variables.

Comment: "Here $\delta_0$ is the degenerate random variable" Actually $\delta_0$ is a probability measure, not a random variable.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Siince $a_n\rightarrow 0$ and $b_n\rightarrow 0$ there exists $n_0$ s.t. $|a_n|\vee |b_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge n_0$ so that

$$P\{|X_n|>\epsilon\}\le P\{|X_n|>|a_n|\vee|b_n|\}\rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n\rightarrow \infty$$

Hence, $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability (and in distribution).

Comment: Is there a possibility that you could solve this problem WITHOUT using convergence in probability? As you see, this problem is on distributional convergence and convergence in probability is not yet taught. Though I know it, I am possibly not allowed to use it.

Comment: Sure. You need to show that the CDFs of $X_n$ converge to $1\{x≥0\}$ for all continuity points i.e. $\mathbb{R}\text{\\}\{0\}$.

Comment: You have $P\{|X_n|>\epsilon\}\rightarrow 0$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ which means that $F_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ for $x<0$ and $1-F_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ for $x>0$ (where $F_n$ is the CDF of $X_n$).

Comment: If $x>0$ then there exists $N$ such that $\forall n>N$, $a_n\leq b_n<x$ so $P(X_n\leq x)\geq P(a_n\leq X_n\leq b_n)\to1$ so $P(X_n\leq x)\to1$ if $x>0$. I am stumped when $x<0$, mainly in want of a suitable inequality.

Comment: $P\{X_n\le x\}\ge P\{X_n \le b_n\}$ for $x>0$ and $P\{X_n\le x\}\le P\{X_n< a_n\}$ for $x<0$.

Comment: Note that as $P(a_n\leq X_n\leq b_n)\to1$ hence given $\epsilon>0,\exists N\forall n>N, 1+P(X_n<a_n)-\epsilon<P(X_n\leq b_n)\leq1$ This inequality makes sense if $1+P(X_n<a_n)-\epsilon\leq1\forall\epsilon\implies P(X_n<a_n)\leq\epsilon$. Hence $P(X_n<a_n)\to0$. Am I correct?